Short story. Humanity reaches Mars, the whole planet is honeycombed. Aliens rapidly mined everything of any value, then abandoned the planet
I read this after 2000. It seemed a few decades old when I read it. Earth is in a pretty bad way and many humans hope to move to Mars. The first team of astronauts to reach Mars are extraordinarily shocked. The planet is hollow like a honeycomb, every resource of any possible use has been mined.
They believe for a while that the race that exploited Mars so thoroughly went extinct as a consequence. Then they find evidence they all left in spaceships.They were not native to Mars. They arrived, mined everything of any possible value, then abandoned it.
The humans find some data left behind by the race that did this, including some photographs (they might not be photographs)and writing they manage to translate.

 The photo, labelled as the next destination planet of the exploiters, clearly shows Earth.


@user14111 Yeah, this is it. Thank you.
